# Display data ordered in a table

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json, database

I'm displaying a table getting the data in json format coming from an api.
the first column is the timestamp but the api is not giving me the result ordered

So the question would: How can I modify my code so the rows displayed in the table are in order
according to the first column, which would be a number(the timestamp is UNIX 13 digits)?

Thank you very much if somebody could help

Comment: can you add `body` op as well?

Comment: you can use `lodash` library to sort an array of objects by object's property. for your case you can sort the `body` array by `body.timestamp`

Comment: you can use datatable. it provides ajax loading and custom column rendering. it would be easy to integrate and understand in future.

Answer (score 0):

since you have the array with timestamp(unix 13 digit) you can use sort and provide a function to sort the array based on timestamp property.

```
data.sort(
  function(a,b){ 
    
    //use new Date parse string to date type
    //convert date to number use Date.parse()
    //format function(a,b) { return a-b; }
    
    return Date.parse(new Date(a.timestamp)) - Date.parse(new Date(b.timestamp)); 
  }
);
```

```js
var data = [{
    timestamp: "1563398686957",
    country: "Brazil"
  },
  {
    timestamp: "1126398681149",
    country: "USA"
  },
  {
    timestamp: "1123398681149",
    country: "UK"
  },
  {
    timestamp: "1124398681149",
    country: "India"
  },
  {
    timestamp: "1163398681149",
    country: "Canada"
  }
];
$(document).ready(function() {
//sanitize data first
data.forEach(function(x) { x.timestamp = new Date(parseInt(x.timestamp))})
//sort the data
  let sortedData = data.sort(
  function(a,b){ 
    
    //use new Date parse string to date type
    //convert date to number use Date.parse()
    //format function(a,b) { return a-b; }
    
    return Date.parse(a.timestamp) - Date.parse(b.timestamp); 
  }
);

  var table = $("<table><tr><th>timestamp</th><th>country</th></tr>");
  var tr;
  for (var i = 0; i < sortedData.length; i++) {


    tr = $("<tr>");
    tr.append("<td >" + sortedData[i].timestamp.toString().substr(0,24) + "</td>");
    tr.append("<td>" + sortedData[i].country + "</td>");
    table.append(tr);
  }


  table.append("</table>");
  $("#jsonData").html(table);


});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id="jsonData"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the json so each has a id and then body.sort() before the for command or you can have a look at this

> https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_sort_table.asp